# readme-md-generator not updating version from package JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, readme

Is it possible to have my readme auto update the version of my self published package when I update the package JSON?

Right now the readme (created with `readme-md-generator`) does not the relevant section looks like this:
//readme.md

```
<h1 align="center">Welcome to bla bla </h1>
<p>
  <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/version-1.1.7-blue.svg?cacheSeconds=2592000" />
</p>
```

Whereas in my package JSON it has:

```
{
  "name": "bla bla",
  "version": "1.1.13",
...
}
```

I tried importing the package JSON but that did not work as it displayed as HTML. How can I get this to update? (without manually typing it in each time)

Comment: Do you want readme.md update this? if yes, I don't think it supports javascript yet.

Comment: yes, I would like the readme to auto update when I change the version in the package JSON

Comment: Markdown doesn't support javascript processing. However, you can achieve this using javascript. But markdown will not do this automatically.

Comment: How would I do this with JS?

Comment: You can give it a try: First import your JSON. Then extract the "version" from json into a variable using javascript. Now use this variable anywhere you want within file. And finally output the newly generated readme file.

Comment: I tried that ended up with the plain text of the import statement...

Comment: how you are trying to import?

Comment: `const jpackage = require('./package.json')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196925/discussion-between-sagar-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

The versions badge from `readme-md-generator` is now dynamic if you're project is published on npm. See [this PR](https://github.com/kefranabg/readme-md-generator/commit/0a11d2ae3a7ea767e4f0138f7b1d21e114fb991a).

Comment: Thanks, my project is published on a private repository so this does not help in my case.